# LangChain - create_sql_agent prompt, though, and observation output

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model

When creating a `create_sql_agent()` how do you get the prompt, thought, and observation?

I know how to get the final answer which is just the response of the `agent_executor.run` but I would like to get the various observations and graph the results.

Code example shows just the "final answer"

```
dbsql = SQLDatabase.from_uri(database)

llm = OpenAI(temperature=0, verbose=True)

toolkit = SQLDatabaseToolkit(llm=llm,db=dbsql)

agent_executor = create_sql_agent(
    llm=OpenAI(temperature=0),
    toolkit=toolkit,
    verbose=True
)

output = agent_executor.run("MY QUESTION")

print(f"Agent Executor output: {output}")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set return_intermediate_steps=True.

```
db_chain = SQLDatabaseChain.from_llm(llm, db, prompt=PROMPT, verbose=True, use_query_checker=True, return_intermediate_steps=True)
```

this would give you

```
result = db_chain("How many employees are there in the foobar table?")
```

result["intermediate_steps"]

*reference:https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/chains/examples/sqlite.html*